# Update json element in json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want to update the "Last" Price of MarketName USDT-BTC, how do I modify "Last" from 16750.00000001 to 17000.00000001 and send it over my api?

```json
{
  "success":true,
  "message":"",
  "result":[{
    "MarketName":"USDT-BTC",
    "High":16937,
    "Low":15280,
    "Volume":6268.37139646,
    "Last":16750.00000001,
    "BaseVolume":101115016.3188782,
    "TimeStamp":"2017-12-15T01:11:19.513",
    "Bid":16749.99999999,
    "Ask":16750,
    "OpenBuyOrders":12099,
    "OpenSellOrders":4901,
    "PrevDay":16143.70987342,
    "Created":"2015-12-11T06:31:40.633"
}]}
```

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    url: 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries',
    method: 'GET',
};

app.get("/api", function(req, res)  {
        request(options, function(err, output, body) {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        delete json['USDT-BTC']; // THIS IS NOT WORKING WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO?
        console.log(json);
        res.json(json)
});

});

app.listen(80, function() {
    console.log("RUNNING: http://localhost/api");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `'USDT-BTC'` is a value not a property and it is in an array nested inside another property. Use `Array#find()` to get that object from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look for the USDT-BTC and change the price:

```
 for (var i in json.result) {
     var item = json.result[i];

     if (item.MarketName == 'USDT-BTC') {
         item.Price = 17000.00000001;
     }
 }
```

Other way using map:

```
 json.result = json.result.map(item => (
     item.MarketName == 'USDT-BTC' ?
         { ...item, price: 17000.00000001} : item );
 )
```

Comment: The option with map is really clean. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you are doing. Why are you deleting something? Fist the object key seems to be "Last" not "USDT-BTC". So you would need to get the Jon object find the correct entry and exit the 'Last' key. Something like var entry = json[0]; entry ['Last']  = "new value":

That is assuming you only have 1 thing in the response and/or it is the first element in the  returned array.